# Company Description in Various Local Business Directories - Duplicate Content?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

If we put our company on various local business directories -- should we create a different company description for each listing to avoid being penalized by search engines for duplicate content?

Comment: Let's just say for a moment that it is duplicate content, how does it effect your site?? It would effect theirs. ;-) However, there are some things that Google expects. Still, it may not hurt to mix it up a bit. It could make the individual page more valuable and therefore the link too. Who knows?? Just make sure your information is accurate and that the NAP (name, address, and phone number) match the contact information on the website. I did a quick search, but Google over-optimizes BS sites with junk information regardless of the query. G follows the group "me too(!)" speak as gospel.